# A bijection between certain sequences and functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $n$ be a natural number. I let define $S_n$ to be number of all possible final results at a competition where ties are possible. More precisely $S_n$ is the set of all functions $f:[n]\to [n]$ such that if $f$ takes the value $i$ then $\forall j, 1\le j\le i$, it also takes the value $j$. ($S_0=1$). I wish to prove the recurrence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}S_{n-k}$.

Now I first choose the $k$ elements mapped to $1$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Corresponding to the remaining $n-k$ elements I now consider all functions which preserve the criterion. Each such function can be bijectively identified with a sequence of $n-k$ terms so that the elements of the sequence are in $\{2,3\cdots n\}$ and they are all consecutive integers with possible repetitions. I now wish to show that the collection of all such sequences is in bijective correspondence with $S_{n-k}$ to complete the proof. How can I prove this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick your $k$-element set $K\subseteq[n]$ that is to be sent to $1$. Let $f:[n-k]\to[n-k]$ be arbitrary. There is an order-preserving bijections $\varphi:[n]\setminus K\to[n-k]$, since $|[n]\setminus K|=n-k$. Define

$$\hat f:[n]\to[n]:i\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }i\in K\\
f(\varphi(i))+1,&\text{if }i\in[n]\setminus K\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $\hat f$ has the desired properties, and you need only verify that all result functions that send precisely the set $K$ to $1$ can be obtained uniquely in this way.