# A doubt in the derivation of a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, summation

My question is related to a previous question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362401/a-bijection-between-certain-sequences-and-functions/362415#362415). It is really a very uninteresting sort of a doubt unfortunately. Let $S_n$ be the number of all possible final results at a competition where ties are possible. A recurrence relation (as shown in the linked post) is then $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}S_{n-k}$ so that $\frac{2S_n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{S_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}$.

My doubt is regarding the derivation of the generating function given in the book. The derivation proceeds as follows:

$$\begin{align}2s(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2S_n}{n!}x^n\\\\&=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{S_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^n\\\\&=1+\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{S_m}{m!}x^m\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\\\\&=1+s(x)e^x\end{align}$$

whence $s(x)=\dfrac{1}{2-e^x}$.

My doubt is that I cannot understand the second and third equality signs in the above derivation. I cannot understand how the extra $1$ came about or how the multiplication comes in. Can someone please explain how the come about.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that we define the Cauchy product or convolution of two sequences $a_n,b_n$ as $$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}=\sum_{k+j=n}a_kb_j$$

This is comes from the fact we're "collecting coefficients" in the product:

$$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots)=a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2)x^2+\cdots$$

Now observe that if your coefficients are $$\frac{S_n}{n!}$$ and $$\frac 1{ n!}$$ your convolution will turn out to be $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{S_{n-k}}{(n-k)!k!}=\frac{2S_n}{n!}$$

(You have an $\infty$ on top, it shouldn't be there.)

Also note that $1/n!$ is the $n$-th coefficient in the series expansion at $x=0$ of $e^x$.

Comment: I am not clear about the second equality. Simply substituting $\frac{2S_n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{S_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}$ won't yield any $1$. From where does the extra $1$ come?

Comment: @shahab Look at your previous post. The recurrence shoul start at $k =1$, not $k=0$. It looks like ,that is the problem.

Comment: Actually no. The recurrence for $S_n$ starts at $k=1$ but the recurrence for $\frac{2S_n}{n!}$ starts from $k=0$. I have double checked.

Comment: The "$1 + {}$" looks completely unwarranted, but strangely the result checks out (!?)

Answer (score 1):

Do I feel stupid... for $n \ge 1$ you have:
$$
2 S_n = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} S_{n - k}
$$
but for $n = 0$ it is just $\sum_{0 \le k \le 0} S_k = S_0$, so the full recurrence (for $n \ge 0$ now) is:
$$
2 S_n = [n = 0] S_0 + \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} S_{n - k}
$$
The [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) provides the mistery $S_0 = 1$.

Comment: I guess that is it. =)